# Why do my windows shade (roll up) on scroll when my cursor is at the right edge of a maixmized window?

Tags: mouse-scroll

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and whenever I have a window maximized and use the scroll wheel while the cursor is on the right edge, the window rolls up. This is annoying since the scroll bar is on the right edge and I'm trying to scroll up the page but my cursor moves to the very edge and the whole window rolls up. Is this a new behaviour that can be disabled? or is this a bug that should be reported elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can config the Window Manager (the software which handles the graphic enviroment's behaviour) following:

> MENU: System --> Preferences --> Confguration Editor

Find "Metacity" (I assume you're using Gnome) on the left and change any option you want: feel free to experiment, any change is reversible.
The entry which you need should be in:`/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/toggle_shaded`.
Have a nice experience.

Comment: Sorry, you are referring to the action of hovering the mouse cursor over the TITLEBAR and scrolling to shade the window. But this behavior is happening when the mouse cursor is over the RIGHT EDGE OF A MAXIMISED WINDOW. Not the same thing. This behavior is not controlled by the Configuration Editor and is quite unintuitive as I explained above.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error. If you can't find a solution you can still substitute Metacity with another window manager like `mutter`, which is born to be an excellent substitute for Metacity.